# jquery ajax response not showing on jqueryui dialog window

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to show blog details when a link is clicked.

Here is part of the code I have.

".ajax" part

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'someurl',
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function( response ) {
            $( '#viewDialog > h1' ).html( response.title );
            $( '#viewDialog > p' ).html( response.content );

            $( '#viewDialog' ).dialog( 'open' );
        }
    });
```

".html" part

```
<div id="viewDialog" title="My Blog">
    <h1></h1>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

I am pretty sure I get the response from the server in the right json format.
Something like this
`{"id":"120","title":"My new stuff","content":"Someting new","author_id":"11"}`

When I clicked the link, the dialog window poped up but no information was shown in the window.

Did I do everything right?

Milo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no element with an ID of `blogDetail` in the HTML you provided.

**Edit after question update:**

Passing `'open'` into the dialog call will only work if the dialog was previously created.

Placing `$( '#viewDialog' ).dialog({autoOpen:false});` at the top of your jQuery script should make this work.

Or you could simply remove the 'open' parameter and just call `$( '#viewDialog' ).dialog();`

[Demo using { autoOpen : false }](http://jsfiddle.net/9acKR/3/)

[Demo without Passing 'open'](http://jsfiddle.net/9acKR/4/)

Answer (score 2):

Almost, by the looks of things - try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'someurl',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( response ) {
        $( '#viewDialog > h1').html( response.title );
        $( '#viewDialog > p' ).html( response.content );

        $( '#viewDialog' ).dialog( 'open' );
    }
});
```

You didn't define an ID of blogDetail that I could see.  It looks like you're trying to put the HTML into viewDialog.

Comment: I think I pasted a wrong code. I have updated my question. In fact, the code I had trouble with was exact the same as your answer. Still the dialog window pops up but no information on it. Further help is appreciated.

Comment: is that all of your code?  Have you included JQuery UI and initialised a dialog box before trying to open it?